# Issue when trying to toggle the dropdown sub menu in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jsfiddle multi level sub menu dropdown https://jsfiddle.net/x4wshtqg/

How to add a method to open the sub menus in Vuejs,  At present dropdown is showing only items in dropdown. But it is not showing the sub menu list in dropdown.

```html
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){ $(this).next('ul').toggle(); e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }); });
```

Above is the jquery code (method), But i need to write the above jquery to vuejs method.
And need to display accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing setting the element to your vue instance. Once that's done, you can create a method and bind it to an event in your template. That method has access to jquery and the element via `event.target` and you can run it that way.

Here's an updated Fiddle doing the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/gs4j6k30/2/